# Get return value of a class method in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, class, methods, jupyter-notebook, return-value

I have a folder called `MyModule` that contains an `__init__.py` file with the following contents:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5

    def MyOutput(self):
        return self.x
```

Next to the `MyModule` folder I put a jupyter notebook `MyNotebook.ipynb` which contains the following code in a single cell:

```
from MyModule import MyClass
myClass = MyClass()
myClass.MyOutput()
```

Now, I would have expected to see the output `5` below the cell after evaluating it. Instead there just is no output at all. I suspect that I am doing something wrong with the syntax. How should I fix it to have it display the output `5` after evaluating the cell in jupyter notebook?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me. Have you tried, whether it behaves the same if you add a function to MyModule, which also returns an int?

Comment: @TodorTodorov turns out, I just had to restart the jupyter kernel, because it had an older version of my class in memory and did not reload it fresh.